# Android Studio gradle assert error

Tags: gradle, android-studio

After upgrading to AS 0.3.1 I get an error when trying to run the app from AS:

```
    java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.config.GradleScriptType$1.configureCommandLine(GradleScriptType.java:221)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.runner.GroovyScriptRunConfiguration$1.createJavaParameters(GroovyScriptRunConfiguration.java:204)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.JavaCommandLineState.getJavaParameters(JavaCommandLineState.java:35)
...
```

This is the gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
    }
}
...
```

Building works without complaints.

Is this a known bug? Do I need to do something to update the gradle plugin?

Comment: Try to delete `user_folder\.gradle` cache and restart idea. This can be problems with downloading gradle. Make sure you connection is good and you give enought time for studio to download gradle.

Comment: Tried this yesterday and seemed not to work, but then all of a sudden the problem was fixed, so this was probably the solution after all.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the .gradle folder in C:\Users{$your_user} then restart the Android Studio. 
I had the same problem and that seem to solve it.

Comment: This worked for the equivalent `/Users/myUserName/.gradle` folder on OSX, too.